# Kotlin detect timeout on request to server

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi I'm still new to kotlin language, when requesting data to server for example in java:

```
try{
    request_server();
}
catch(IOException e){
    //Some toast for network timeout for example
}
```

How can I check if that request if have network timeout in Kotlin?

Comment: Not clear what's your problem

Comment: so when request to server like POST connection can be timeout if too long then throws some Exception to java
how can i detect this in Kotlin when they don't have checked Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin does not have checked exceptions but that does not mean you cannot catch an `IOException` in Kotlin. There's no difference except the variable declaration in `catch`:

```
try{
    request_server();
}
catch(e: IOException){
    //Some toast for network timeout for example
}
```

It's very rare that you see such constructs in the language though. Since Kotlin has wonderful support for higher order functions, you can extract the error handling into such a function and make the business logic more obvious and also enable reuse.

```
fun <R> timeoutHandled(block: () -> R): R {
    try {
        return block()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        //Some toast for network timeout for example
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
val result = timeoutHandled {
    requestServer()
}
```